# Possibility to host site content on one domain and access it via another

Tags: dns, cross-domain, hosting, web-hosting, cname

I have site1.domain1.com and site2.domain1.com

Is it possible to access to site2.domain1.com via domain2.com via cname or some other possibility?

So idea is to has content hosted at our server and allow user to access it via their own domain.

Is it possible somehow?

thanks
Regards,
Ilija

Answer (score 0):

Both domain should point to same IP direction to get the same site. You need to configure your second domain **domain2.com** with same IP direction than **site2.domain1.com**

Comment: Can you please explain this more detailed? Is it zone editor in cpanel https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/6721674?key=da6292a25a6dbe6b9d562eb5d349df89

Comment: You have to edit your domain2.com, Type "A" using same direction than another domain. Domain just are nicknames for not to use IP direction directly.

Comment: So, you are saying that I should point site2.domain2.com to IP address of site1.domain1.com so that site2domain2 is showing content of site1.domain1?
But how I will point it to subdomain? I get it for domain, it is simple IP address.

Comment: I think depends on your DNS, I think is possible, check out this articule: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain/